# WordPress: too many queries to the database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have just moved a WP installation from one hosting provider to another. Everything went fine except for a problem I have with the new installation. Please note that I have moved from a regular VPS to a kinda powerful and fast dedicated machine.

The thing is that now, the website is slower than when in the previous server. It takes 6-7 seconds to load a page and according to Chrome's Dev Tools network panel, it has a period of 3-4 seconds to the get the first response byte (TTFB), which is insane.

I have tried the following with no success:

- Review database for anomalies
- Disable all plugins (and delete them)
- Disable template (and delete it)

With these last two actions, I lowered the loading time to 5-6 seconds, which is a lot for small site (a few hundreds of posts and 50-60 pages), with no comments enabled. I still have the 3-4 TTFB period.

After that, I installed the Query Monitor plugin and found out that, at every page load, WP performs hundreds (ranging from 400 to 800) database queries and, in some cases, even 1500 database queries. OMG!

Honestly, I am quite lost here. I mean, on one hand I have this strange database behavior I cannot really understand. And on the other hand, I cannot help wondering how it was faster on the previous & slower server.

By the way, I have moved from MySQL to MariaDB, which should be even faster too. Indexes are kept when dumping & importing the file. I am lost. :(

Any help is greatly appreciated. Apologies for my english (not my language) and please let me know if the is some important information missing. I will be glad to provide all the necessary information that help me/us troubleshoot this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you is under attack, have tried protect you domain with services like Cloudflare?Maybe help you to understand what happen. Use Jetpack plugin protect too, is very effective.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should optimize your MySQL config (my.cnf in Linux or my.ini in Windows). To view problems in MySQL you can try run the script MySQLTuner: https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl.